# mounting driver in linux whm

Tags: linux, server, mount, vds

hello i tried so many code i found on blogs but keep getting error, i bought a new server of 2TB only 1TB is available, now i am trying to mount the remain 1TB, please can any one help me?.
below is my server info

> CPU1: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor (Cores 16)

> Memory:  128767 MB

> Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1024 GB (=> 953 GiB) doesn't contain a valid partition table

> Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 1024 GB (=> 953 GiB) doesn't contain a valid partition table
> Total capacity 1907 GiB with 2 Disks

and when i run  `sudo lsblk`

output

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:2    0     4G  0 part
│ └─md0       9:0    0     4G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p2 259:3    0     1G  0 part
│ └─md1       9:1    0  1022M  0 raid1 /boot
└─nvme0n1p3 259:4    0 948.9G  0 part
  └─md2       9:2    0 948.8G  0 raid1 /
nvme1n1     259:1    0 953.9G  0 disk
├─nvme1n1p1 259:5    0     4G  0 part
│ └─md0       9:0    0     4G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─nvme1n1p2 259:6    0     1G  0 part
│ └─md1       9:1    0  1022M  0 raid1 /boot
└─nvme1n1p3 259:7    0 948.9G  0 part
  └─md2       9:2    0 948.8G  0 raid1 /
```

thank you, hoping to get a respond soon

Comment: Your disks are RAID 1.

Comment: Explain please, and give me guide and tips

Comment: https://www.techtarget.com/searchstorage/definition/RAID

Comment: OK so you are saying I only have 1tb to use?

Comment: Hello please I am waiting for your responses please